# What is a better way of including header files in a C++ code?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, header-files

This is a console based Maze Game. The idea is to write the game class in a header file and use the class in the main thread. I am not sure if I am doing it right because I get an error.  How would I include a header file in my code?

I am using Cloud9 so I don't know if there is a difference between Cloud9 and application software IDE. I am very new to C++, only been using it for some weeks (3-4), so I would like to know if what I am doing it right.

Here is how my code is structured:

This is **MazeGame.h:**

```
#ifndef MAZEGAME_H
#define MAZEGAME_H

class Maze{
protected: 
    int width;
    int height;
    std::string maze;

public:
    Maze(int width, int height){
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }

    static void setMazeBlock(std::string value){
        this->maze += value;
    }

    void destroyMazeBlock(int set){
        this->maze[set] -= this->maze[set];
    }

    std::string getMazeDrawing(){
        return this->maze;
    }

    void setMazeDrawing(std::string val){
        this->maze = val;
    }

    void drawMaze(int times = 1){

        for(int i = 0; i <= times; ++i){
            std::cout << this->maze;
        }
    }

    void generate(){
        for(int i = 0; i < this->width; ++i){
                this->setMazeBlock("#");
        }
        this->setMazeBlock(std::endl);
        for(int i = 0; i < this->width; ++i){
            this->setMazeBlock("#"); 
            for(int j = 0; j < this->height; ++j){
                this->setMazeBlock(std::endl);
                if(j == this->width){
                    this->setMazeBlock("#");
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < this->width; ++i){
                this->setMazeBlock("#");
        }
        this->setMazeBlock(std::endl);
    }
};
```

This is **MazeGame.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <MazeGame.h>

int main(){
    Maze m = new Maze(16, 16);

    return 0;

}
```

Both files are in the same directory. However, I am getting this error on the console:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Maze/MazeGame.cpp:4:22: fatal error: MazeGame.h: No such file or directory
#include <MazeGame.h>
                   ^
```

Comment: You should use `#include <XXX.h>` for builtin headers and `#include "XXX.h"` for user-defined headers.

Comment: Please remove your `this->` notation, it is not needed in C++.  The C++ language is not java.

Comment: You may want to move larger method definitions to a source file, which should speed up your build process.

Comment: IMO, your header file should `#include <string>` since you use for the members in your class declaration.

Comment: I recommend using the extension "hpp" for C++ files and ".h" for C language files.  This becomes important when mixing C language files with C++ files.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not know `this->` was not needed. Is it only needed for variables or when do you need to use it? I am getting a new error on `MazeGames.h`: `In file included from /home/ubuntu/workspace/Maze/MazeGame.cpp:2:0:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Maze/MazeGame.h:1:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef MAZEGAME_H
 ^`

Comment: @XBM: You require `#endif` at the end of MazeGame.h. Every `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` block must be terminated with `#endif`.

Comment: @XBM you only need `this->` when you declare another variable that hides the name of the member. (Plus an additional case which you won't have to care about until much later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your header file is **user-defined**, you should declare it with double quotes:

```
#include "MazeGame.h"
```

The way you were trying to declare it is the method you would use for **built-in** headers. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: what's if the op adds the folder containing the header `MazeGame.h` to the compiler's include directory??!!! it will wok fine. look for example at MSVC++ 15 `Additional include folders`

Answer (score 2):

The includes should be:

```
#include <iostream>       // <...>  for standard headers
#include "MazeGame.h"     // "..."  for your own headers
```

The error comes from using `<...>` for your own headers, which causes the compiler looking for your header in the wrong place.

You could also consider moving the member function definitions in the cpp file, leaving in the header only their signature declaration:

**header file :**

```
class Maze{
protected: 
    ...
public:
    Maze(int width, int height); 
    static void setMazeBlock(std::string value); 
    ...
};
```

**cpp file:**

```
Maze::Maze(int width, int height){
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}
void Maze::destroyMazeBlock(int set){
    maze[set] -= maze[set];     // n need for this-> here
}
...
```

By the way, it's a good practice to make [headers self sufficient](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Self_contained_Headers), so to include in the header the other headers they rely on, without expecting that you'll do it in the cpp (so due to the std::string, an include of `<string>` in the header would be advisable.

Answer (score 1):

> fatal error: MazeGame.h: No such file or directory `#include <MazeGame.h>`

Compiler cannot find `MazeGame.h` file on the search path.

The difference between `#include "MazeGame.h"` and `#include <MazeGame.h>` is the pathes where compiler searches for the header file. Cloud9 uses GCC compiler, which specifies [include syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) this way:

> `#include <file>` It searches for a file named `file` in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the -I option
>
> `#include "file"` It searches for a file named `file` first in the directory containing the current file, then in the quote directories and then the same directories used for `<file>`. You can prepend directories to the list of quote directories with the -iquote option

So for user-defined headers you should use `"file"` and in your code above: `#include "MazeGame.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

writing `#include <>` is not necessary but by default for built-in but just for your compilers include directories.

so if you want to write this way and work then:

- add the folder of your new header files to include of your compiler then you can write:

  ```
  #include<MazeGame.h>
  ```
- or you can copy this header file to include folder and it will work fine. an example when installing new library like openGL we copy header to `include folder` and `lib` files to lib folder.

by default `include ""` is used telling the compiler that the file is in the current working directory.

- you can also write: `#include <iostream>` so the compiler in this case searches for iostream in the current directory and if it doesn't find it it searches for it in compiler's all include folders (built-in and added directories)

Comment: sorry I meant: `#include "iostream"`

Comment: This answer would be more useful, if it contained references to the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

The user-defined header file, the syntax to include in the `.cpp` file is

```cpp
#include "userdefined.h"
```